# questions about predicting time series using gaussian process regression

Tags: time-series, prediction, gaussian-process

I am using gaussian process regression to predict a time series. The time series is number of daily active users(DAU) of an APP, and takes daily numbers of  installing users and uninstalling users as X(independent variable).

I using this model to see the influence of installing and uninstalling on DAU.
But when the number of installing and uninstalling is real, the model works very well and predict very accurately. But when I set installing number a positive const, and uninstalling number to be zero, the DAU should increase, but the model cannot predict increasing DAU, but a const DAU.

I know the reason why the model behaves like this. Since the X is the same, than the DAU predicted is also the same. I want to know how to handle this problem. Thanks.